# Mariadb trigger to invoke a python code

Tags: python, python-2.7, mariadb, database-trigger

I have a python code to be executed when a database table is updated. How can I write a Mariadb trigger for the same?

Answer (score 3):

By default MariaDB doesn't support execution of external programs.

As a workaround you can call a udf (user defined function) which executes python interpreter. lib_mysqludf_sys from [UDF Repository for MySQL](https://github.com/mysqludf) might be the right udf for.

So your trigger definition might look like

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON my_tbl
  ....
  SET RC= sys_exec('/usr/bin/python my_script.py');
  ....
```

Comment: Have tried it. I am cyurrently using Fedora24. Unable to install mysqludf here.

Comment: The error I get is "You need libmysqlclient development software installed". However, I am using mariadb. So the corresponding package is mariadb-devel, which is already installed.

Comment: git clone https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys - the shared object in this repo doesn't depend on libmysqlclient.

Comment: I used the same repo. In the install.sh file, the code is as follows:

Comment: if test $? -ne 0; then
 echo "ERROR: You need libmysqlclient development software installed "
 echo "to be able to compile this UDF, on Debian/Ubuntu just run:"
 echo "apt-get install libmysqlclient15-dev"
 exit 1